# Spring security login form always redirect to authfailed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to apply spring security to a login form.
Here is the login form:

```
<form:form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post" modelAttribute="userLogin">
<p>UserName: </p> <form:input type="text" path="name" />
<p>Password: </p> <form:input type="password" path="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form:form>
```

And here is the spring security xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <access-denied-handler />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/mainPage"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>
<authentication-manager> <authentication-provider> <user-service> <user 
        name="user" password="user@123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> </user-service> 
        </authentication-provider> </authentication-manager>
```

When i submit the form, it is redirected to the url 'http://localhost:8080/SecurityTest/login?authfailed' even if i entered the right user name and password.

Comment: Yes it will fail, see my [answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335602/spring-security-error-forbidden-response-from-rest-endpoint/32338707#32338707

Comment: But, when i use a normal form (not spring), it works right without switching off CSRF.
The problem is in using the spring tags.
Also, when i use a normal form, and put this in the action `<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />` , it redirects to the right url. When using spring tags, it doesn't understand this action!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="action" />

<form:form action="${action}" method="post" modelAttribute="userLogin">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was in the path variable in the form:input tag.
It should be named `username` while i was naming it `name`.